# c# conditional OrderBy

Tags: c#, linq, linq-to-sql, lambda

I have an `Article` entity with following structure

```
public class Article
{
    public decimal Price {get;set;}
    public decimal? SalePrice {get;set;}
    public bool OnSale {get;set;}
}
```

What I need to do is to query articles by their price by following criteria:
If article is on sale, take it's sale price, if not, take it's regular price.

So for an example:

- Article A (OnSale  = True, Price = 10, SalePrice = 5)
- Article B (ONSale = False, Price = 4, SalePrice = NULL)
- Article C (OnSale = False, Price = 22, SalePrice = 10)

When ordering by price, order should be

B (price 4)

A (price 5) - cause it's sale price

C (price 22)

I tried with

```
IQueryable<Article> articlesQuery = dal.Where<Article>(m => m.Active);
articlesQuery = articlesQuery.OrderBy(m => m.OnSale ? m.PriceSale : m.PriceSale);
```

but it does not give desired result.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Why are you using `PriceSale` twice in the lambda?

Comment: Apart from the mentioned and solved issue, I don't think it is a great design to store a price with an article for many reasons. Why not introduce an ArticlePrice and `public ICollection<ArticlePrice> ArticlePrices { get; set; }` property? Only one price can be valid for a period of time, and you can have multiple overlapping sales. Whether a certain price is a sale price or a one-time discount can then be registered in the `ArticlePrice`.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Both sides of the if are the same variable? (And not a variable in the above class).
should it not be:

```
articlesQuery = articlesQuery.OrderBy(m => m.OnSale ? m.SalePrice: m.Price);
```

Comment: thanks for the remark. After long working day, i did not saw that trivial mistake :) I will set my question to be deleted

Answer (score -1):

You could do this with an additional read only property on `Article` to make the code slightly easier to read :

```
public class Article
{
    public decimal NormalPrice { get; set; }
    public decimal? SalePrice { get; set; }
    public bool OnSale { get; set; }

    public decimal Price
    {
        get
        {
            if (this.OnSale)
            {
                return this.SalePrice.Value;
            }
            else
            {
                return this.NormalPrice;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

And use it :

```
IQueryable<Article> articlesQuery = dal.Where<Article>(m => m.Active);
articlesQuery = articlesQuery.OrderBy(m => m.Price);
```

Comment: No this wont. I should have seen you are using a DAL.